# MSBuild Web packaging: Sources vs Binaries folder

Tags: msbuild-4.0

I can't understand why MSBuild generates 2 folders on build server each time you queue a new build, Sources and Binaries.

I have a web project deployed with a folder called Areas, containing views (.vbhtml) and DLLs which come from another project. These are properly generated in Binaries folder but the thing is MSBuild keeps packaging the project from Sources folder (.zip file generation).

Does anybody know how to tell MSBuild to package my web projects from Binaries folder and not from Sources anymore?

There is no documentation about this on MSDN site.

Thanks in advance for your help.